# jQuery changing css property by variable value

Tags: jquery, css, height

Trying to get 100% height based on window size.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var contHeight = $(window).height();
        $('#container').css("height",contHeight + "px");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: It's not working.  HTML is standard layout format.

    <div id="header">
      <h1>Stuff</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="container">
      <h1> More Stuff</h1>
    </div>

Right now, the Container div does not display at all.

Comment: What exactly is the problem, are you getting any errors? did you try doing a `alert(contHeight)`

Comment: What is'nt working, is the height not set to the same as the window, does the height not update when resizing, if that's the intended effect, does anything work at all, there are a lot of things you can add to make your question understandable to others, and "not working" is not one of those things. Did you set a position and width on your element, and is it visible, ie. not set to display none etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WOrking FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/mzpa4/

Comment: Thanks.  So problem was with syntax using the quote marks?

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try:

```
$(window).on('load resize',function(){
    var contHeight = $(window).height();
    $('#container').css("height",contHeight + "px");
});
```

So that the height sticks to window height even if users resize window, as @adeneo suggested

http://jsfiddle.net/mzpa4/3/show/

Comment: Cool trick, thanks.  Didn't realize how much this would matter until I had an inspection window open.

Comment: If user resizes window after loading the page, the height of containe will auto adjust. There are also pure CSS solutions out there for some cases, search for 100% height with CSS.

Comment: I've been shifting a lot more towards jQuery for things like structure because of the ease of cross browser support.  It's easier to implement the code than to get people to stop using IE.